# Jetty error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/TransactionDefinition

Tags: spring, jetty

0.0.M2 and Spring for a web application.
The question is that the war file can be deployed on Tomcat and execute correctly on Tomcat. But it cannot work on jetty. I run jetty as standalone program. That is to say I just copy the war file into the webapp directory of jetty and use "java -jar start.jar"

HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /IOServer/schema/loadschemalist.json. Reason:

```
org/springframework/transaction/TransactionDefinition
```

Caused by:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/TransactionDefinition
    at com.fixflyer.service.aggregation.Aggregator.createMessageProcessor(Aggregator.java:47)
    at com.fixflyer.service.configuration.ConfigService.loadSchema(ConfigService.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:710)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:167)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:402)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:956)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:891)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:1076)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:805)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:510)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.access$000(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:450)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:370)
    ... 40 more

Caused by:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:370)
    at com.fixflyer.service.aggregation.Aggregator.createMessageProcessor(Aggregator.java:47)
    at com.fixflyer.service.configuration.ConfigService.loadSchema(ConfigService.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:710)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:167)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:402)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:956)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:891)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:1076)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:805)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:510)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.access$000(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:450)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Powered by Jetty://

Answer (score 7):

Add this dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: In case one wants to look up the current version: [here's the link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx)

Comment: This worked for me. Got the same error using Cucumber. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I was facing this issue while running specific cucumber scenario test in IntelliJ, I had to remove 
"cucumber.api.spring" in Glue section in Edit Configuration.

[Reference Link](https://foreach.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/CWB/blog/2015/07/02/9404422/Quick-fix+for+issues+with+IntelliJ+14.1.3+)